# cannot resolve urllib3 version issue

Tags: python, urllib3, adobe-pdfservices

I am trying to use Adobe's pdfservices-sdk and am getting the following error

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages 
that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
pdfservices-extract-sdk 1.0.0b1 requires urllib3==1.26.3, but you have urllib3 1.26.8 
which is incompatible.
Successfully installed urllib3-1.26.8
```

When I instead install version 1.26.3, it says that it is incompatible and requires 1.26.8.

I keep going back and forth, it is not working. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that your Python environment already has urllib3 installed, and something requires its version different than the one needed by *pdfservices-sdk*.  There's two options:

1. Use [venv — Creation of virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) or [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) to isolate Python environment for playing with *pdfservices-sdk* from all the others (I've just installed 1.0.0b1 in *venv* and it pulled urllib 1.26.3 with no problem).
2. Install bleeding edge version of *pdfservices-sdk* directly from Github:

   ```
   pip install https://github.com/adobe/pdfservices-python-sdk/archive/master.zip
   ```

   This bleeding edge version has [*urllib3* version bumped to 1.26.8](https://github.com/adobe/pdfservices-python-sdk/commit/c559eefdddd2d22271350efdec3ac9f8af57b91d)

Answer (score 2):

It appears you installed both `pdfservices-extract-sdk 1.0.0b1` and `pdfservices-sdk 1.0.2`.

The former is the predecessor of the latter. You can `pip uninstall pdfservices-extract-sdk`.

Docs:

- Old (Beta program access) mentions `pip install pdfservices-extract-sdk`: https://opensource.adobe.com/pdftools-sdk-docs/beta/extract/index.html#set-up-a-python-environment
- New mentions `pip install pdfservices-sdk`: https://developer.adobe.com/document-services/docs/overview/pdf-services-api/#set-up-a-python-environment

pypi.org package histories:

- `pdfservices-extract-sdk 1.0.0b1` released May 10, 2021 ([history](https://pypi.org/project/pdfservices-extract-sdk/#history))
- `pdfservices-sdk 1.0.0` released Jun 7, 2021 ([history](https://pypi.org/project/pdfservices-sdk/#history))
- `pdfservices-sdk 1.0.1` released Aug 10, 2021
- `pdfservices-sdk 1.0.2` released Jan 17, 2022
- `pdfservices-sdk 1.0.2b1` released Mar 21, 2022

GitHub repo releases: https://github.com/adobe/pdfservices-python-sdk/releases